# getting external imported python built-in function code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to open a function source code of an added library in python, is it possible, i used to do it in matlab but not in python environment

Comment: What do you mean by open? Have you tried to import the function?

Comment: Yes i added the while packafe and worked but i want to open the code file itself as i used to do in matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your function name is foo.

Do

```
import inspect

print(inspect.getsource(foo))
```